# Google Go error - "cannot make type"

Tags: compiler-errors, go

In my Go code I want to make an array of custom data type. I call

```
Blocks=make(*BlockData, len(blocks))
```

and I get error:

```
cannot make type *BlockData
```

my class BlockData contains such field types as uint64, int64, float32, string, []byte, []string and []*TransactionData. The last one is an array of pointers to another custom class of mine.

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`make()` is used to create slices, maps and channels. The type name must have `[]` before it when making a slice.

Use this to make a slice of pointers to BlockData.

```
Blocks = make([]*BlockData, len(blocks))
```

Read more in the [Go language specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Making_slices_maps_and_channels).

Answer (score 1):

[Making slices, maps and channels](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type BlockData struct{}

func main() {
    blocks := 4
    Blocks := make([]*BlockData, blocks)
    fmt.Println(len(Blocks), Blocks)
}
```

Output:

```
4 [<nil> <nil> <nil> <nil>]
```